# Access T from RwLock<Vec<RwLock<T>>>

Tags: asynchronous, rust, concurrency, rust-tokio

I have a struct that should be passed around multiple threads. It is structured as follows:

```
pub struct State{
    humans: RwLock<Vec<RwLock<Human>>,
    animals: RwLock<Vec<RwLock<Animal>>
}
```

The idea is that if threads are only writing to single Vec elements, not the whole Vec is being locked, but just the respective elements and all the others can be read. On the other hand, when inserting / deleting from Vec, it for sure gets fully locked.

Now I also have a function, that returns a specific `Human`. For simplicity, it always returns `N^2` element.

```
impl State{
    pub fn get_some_element(&self, N: usize) -> &Human{
        // here i am a bit lost, because I run into temporary variables that cannot be passed, when unwrapping the LockGuards. 
    }
}
```

One idea I had, was to use `tokio::sync::RwLockReadGuard::map`:

```
let humans = self.humans.read().await;
RwLockReadGuard::map(humans, |f|{
    &f.get(N^2)
}
```

Even this cannot be returned (so a LockGuard to the respective element) because of temporary variables.

Can you help me here and give some advice on how to resolve that issue effectively? Thank you.

Comment: Lock-in-lock can't really be handled because the inner lock guard borrows the outer lock guard, which means you can't just return both guards since the outer lock guard cannot be removed while borrowed. You may need something like `RwLock<Vec<Arc<RwLock<T>>>>` or you may need to rethink the data structure.

Comment: I meant to say "cannot be moved" not "cannot be removed."

Comment: If the Vecs themselves are not mutated, why don't you use `Arc<[RwLock<T>]>` instead?

Comment: @RichardNeumann the Vecs are also being mutated from time to time. But I would like to have the possibility to w-lock either the whole Vec(in case I mutate the Vec) or just a single element (in case I just mutate one element -> can still read the others)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get a simple reference from a lock. Even outside of the nested lock situation, this does not work:

```rust
fn read_lock(lock: &std::sync::RwLock<i32>) -> &i32 {
    lock.read().unwrap()
}
```

The reason is that `read().unwrap()` gives you a [`RwLockReadGuard`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLockReadGuard.html). It looks a little bit like a shared reference, but it is not. In particular, it is a struct which has its own destructor, which, when executed, releases the lock. You cannot get this post-expiry behaviour with simple references in Rust.

Also, just to emphasise this point: nested locks don't make a difference here. There still must be *some* code to execute that is responsible for releasing *each* lock. Just looking at the signature, we should expect something of the form `RwLockReadGuard<RwLockReadGuard<Human>>` in the return type. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem directly achievable. The stdlib `RwLock` does not have any `map` function, and the `tokio` one is only useful if you can get the inner contents as a simple reference, not as another thing protected by a lock guard (and `async` also gets in the way a little bit).

So at this point I would suggest either changing the return type to something that leaks a bit more of the data structure (e.g. return a lock rather than a reference to the contents), as suggested in the comments; or maybe change the interface to use a closure to work with the acquired reference (similar to the `with` method on `RefCell` and similar):

```rust
fn with_element<R, F: FnOnce(&Human) -> R>(&self, n: usize, f: F) -> R { ... }
```